# Domain registrar that will allow separate sub domain NS record

Tags: domains, subdomain, domain-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

So I recently found out to my dismay that my domain name registrar does not even support sub domains?!

Hence I need to get a new one quick.

I am faced with a problem where by my company has just signed up to an (legit) bulk email provider.

I want to:

- have a domain abc.com which host a website and also has MX records set up to route email as well.
- I also want to set up a sub domain news.abc.com and re-point the whole name server for this sub domain to the bulk email provider.

A couple of the well known domain registrars do not provide this service.

Does anyone have any recommendations of flexible domain companies?  Note I am not a sys-admin more a web dev so would prefer not to have to manually edit zone files!

Thanks

Comment: @John/toomanymiles - I appreciate you are well rated & obviously know what you are talking about however...I am asking a quite specific question regarding having a separate NS record for a sub domain from the NS rec of the parent domain.  Domain names are not mentioned in the proposed duplicate question - also I can not find any other reference to a similar question.  I am not asking a generic 'what domain company should I use'  -  I have a specific case that ordinary registrars can not apparently accommodate - can explain the closure - or provide another question that *is* the same? Thanks.

Comment: @John / toomanyairmiles - I have edited the title to hopefully better reflect my question - on retrospect the title might have seemed a little generic.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what domain name registrars do. They only register the main domain name. You then have to configure the domain name to point at a name server, which may be with the same company or a different one. You then configure the nameservers with the subdomain info.

Comment: @Paulmorriss Thanks for your comment - However I do understand how domain names work and have set up many sites with different NS / DNS multi company hook ups.  My questions is that This is the first time that I have have had to set up a different name server for both the parent and sub domain.  I have spoken to three popular domain registrars and they will not permit me to do this through their control panel.  I am looking for a registrar that will.  Note I am not talking about just setting a different A / MX record for the sub domain.  Thanks.